# Socks5 proxy requests stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: proxy, socks5-proxy

Good Day.

I want to set up a socks5 proxy so I can feed requests through my server with a different IP. I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 and this is done through DigitalOceans Droplets (VPSes)

This has been working for years for me and just stopped working and I can’t figure out why. It worked about ~2 weeks ago and just stopped.

On Droplet A (a.b.c.d) I will run the code once I’ve SSH’d in:

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:5678 localhost
```

Note: port 5678 was one chosen at random. On Droplet B (w.x.y.z) I will try and request a web resource via curl webpage through this proxy I've just created.

```
curl -v -x socks5://a.b.c.d:5678 https://www.google.com
```

Normally this is able to work and retrieve the request. Last 24 hours since I have been trying it doesn’t. It gets stuck hanging on the same results:

```
*   Trying a.b.c.d:5678...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

Then it hangs and never finishes the requests. Both droplets can curl google without a proxy with success. B can both ping and ssh into A. I’ve tried rebooting, recreating droplets with new IPs, different ports same result every time. I’ve also tried playing with dante-server and same issue. I am not an expert in ubuntu so I don’t know what else to try or what could be the problem.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Merci

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know *why* this is the solution, or what changed (os update maybe?).

Opening the port:

```
sudo ufw allow 5678
```

Fixed the problem.